# When echarts is switched on tab, the container width is set to 100%, but no matter how it is set, the width is only 100px

Tags: javascript, echarts

html

js
    var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById("main"));
    window.onresize = myChart.resize;

```
var statistics = {
  title: {
    text: "面积",
    textStyle: {
      fontWeight: "normal",
      color: "#fff", 
      fontSize: 14
    },
    left: "center"
  },
  tooltip: {
    // 鼠标移动柱状图是提示文字
    show: true
  },
  legend: {
    // data: ['面积'],
    textStyle: {
      fontSize: 12
    }
  },

  xAxis: {
    data: ["灌木", "森林", "森林", "树木", "小树", "大树", "红树"],
    axisLabel: {
      show: true,
      textStyle: {
        color: "#fff"
      }
    },
    axisLine: {
      lineStyle: {
        color: "#094060"
      }
    }
  },

  yAxis: {

    axisLine: {
      lineStyle: {
        color: "#094060"
      }
    },
    axisLabel: {
      show: true,
      textStyle: {
        color: "#fff"
      }
    },
    splitLine: {
      lineStyle: {
        color: ["#07405c"]
      }
    }
  },

  itemStyle: {
    color: "#06ae7c",

    emphasis: {
      shadowBlur: 10,
      shadowOffsetX: 0,
      shadowColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)"
    }
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: "bar",
      barWidth: 48, 
      data: [38, 23, 35, 12, 26, 8, 36]
    }
  ]
};

myChart.setOption(statistics);
```

The echarts container in the tab switch width is set to 100%, but no matter how to set the width, are only 100px, the Internet that is because the tab bar tried to hide cause, many of the above methods, are not normal display, followed by window.onresize = myChart.resize in the code; only when changing the size of the browser window to display properly, but if you do not change the size of the window or after 100px, before we have encountered this kind of situation is how to solve?

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered one workaround for this issue. Try to call the resize event of window object when you switch tabs. To achieve it with jQuery is straightforward:

```
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

Answer (score 1):

put the class "echart" in each div chart, and execute that in your js.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
  $(".echart").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('echarts_instance');
    window.echarts.getInstanceById(id).resize();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var myChart=$("#myChart");
myChart.style.width=window.innerWidth+'px';
chartObj=echarts.init(myChart);
chartObj.setOption(option);
```